# Obtaining Build Target in android development

Tags: android

I want to obtain build target in run time and show it on the app. As I know build target is shown when you right click properties and select the android tab. But how can I get it in the code and show in run time on the activity?

Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

You can read out your own `ApplicationInfo`:

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
ApplicationInfo info = pm.getApplicationInfo(
    context.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA );
Log.i( "Info", "Target SDK is: " + info.targetSdkVersion );
```

Answer (score -1):

use Build.VERSION.SDK_INT, it returns a version that app was built on

Comment: Actually, Build.VERSION.SDK_INT shows the device's version of android not the build target.

Comment: Yes, right. But build target - it is info only for IDE, built application have no build target, it has only version of API, that it was built with.

Comment: I want to show every detail about the project. So I asked, it does not matter if it is about IDE or any tool.